# Linux Bash: add prefix to lines if match the condition

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file which contains some lines.

I would like to add a prefix to those lines if it contains some key words.

How do I do that? Thanks!

**Example**:

I want to add `"###"` to the lines with "`Hello`" at the beginning of line:

Current this file has:

```
This is the beginning.
Hello I am Simon.
This is a simple line;
Hello Mike.
This is another line.
```

I want to change this file to:

```
This is the beginning.
###Hello I am Simon.
This is a simple line;
###Hello Mike.
This is another line.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sed program will do that for you. For the example you posted:

```
$ sed 's/^Hello/###Hello/' <file>
```

Comment: Remember to use `sed -i` to write the changes to the file and escape special chars.

Comment: Probably more idiomatic to write `sed '/^Hello/s/^/###/'`.

Answer (score 2):

And awk solution is :

```
awk '{if($1=="Hello"){print "###"$0 ; } else {print $0}}' <file>
```

But I think sed is the better way for this case.

Comment: It is more awkward (which is to say more idiomatic) to write `awk '/^Hello/{printf "###"}1' input-file`